# Mac-like checkbox using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap, can I style my checkboxes to look like Mac ones?
I.e. http://www.flickr.com/photos/wufoo/5761838808/
Thanks

Comment: You don't need Bootstrap, just CSS and Javascript, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It can be really difficult to style form elements...

I use http://formalize.me to normalize for styles across browsers, and as a bonus, it contains lots of useful examples that you can modify to your liking.

This similar question [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css) suggested you use this script

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/